# Gauss integral asymptotics

Tags: integration

I need to know the asymptotic expansion of the Gauss integral

$$\int_0^x e^{ -t^{2}} \mathrm{d}t$$

Is it known for any x as the limit? I am basically substituting the asymptotic expansion of this into another integral.

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DawsonsIntegral.html, formulas (1) and (9). Obviously your naked integral diverges.

Comment: Your integration variable should be different than the variable in the upper limit of integration, otherwise the expression doesn't make sense.

Comment: @gammatester Sorry, I've made a mistake, I meant -x^2, I modified the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $e^{-t^2}$ is extremely quickly decaying for large $|t|$, the integral in $(-\infty,t]$ is virtually equal to the function itself.

$$t<0\to\int_{-\infty}^te^{-t^2}dt\approx e^{-t^2}.$$

[image]

And by symmetry,

$$t>0\to\int_t^{\infty}e^{-t^2}dx\approx e^{-t^2}$$

so that

$$t>0\to\int_0^te^{-t^2}dx\approx\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t^2}dx-e^{-t^2}=\frac{\sqrt\pi}2-e^{-t^2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

You can write this integral as

$$
\int_0^x{\rm d}t~e^{-t^2} = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}{\rm erf}(x) =  \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}[1 - {\rm erfc}(x) ]
$$

And use the [expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Asymptotic_expansion):

$$
{\rm erfc}(x) = \frac{e^{-x^2}}{\sqrt{\pi} x} \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^n\frac{(2n - 1)!!}{(2x^2)^n}
$$